# Javascript Audiocontext Oscillator Not Working on Windows Edge or Android Browsers

Tags: chromium, frequency, volume, audiocontext, javascript-oscillator

The code is complete.
No sound produced.
Tried on Windows Edge Version 109.0.1518.70 (Official build) (64-bit)
Fresh reinstall of Andriod OS and also Windows Install and Upgraded.
I have tried old Audiocontext Oscillator app code
that worked on my previous mobile phones in 2021. Nothing.
All other offline and online sound apps work.

```
alert("your code is ok to run")
var audioContext = new window.AudioContext()
alert("recognise audio object")
var oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
alert("recognise oscillator object")
oscillator.connect(audioContext.destination);
//I am going to say 440
alert(oscillator.frequency.value)
oscillator.start(0)
alert("the code compiled. yeah!, increase the volume. can you hear it? I cant.")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't heat anything it's most likely blocked by the browser's autoplay policy. You need to run your code in response to a user action. If you would for example do it within a button's click handler it should work as expected.

```
document.getElementById('the-id-of-a-button').onclick = () => {
    // the code from above
};
```